# C read multiple words followed by an integer

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read the following text using fscanf. However, I have tried using `"fscanf(ifp, "%[^d\n] %d", title, &stock)"` to read it. But it does not work. The integer is always included in the string and I could not seperate the string part and the integer part.

`Logan 1
Star Wars: Rogue One 5
Monster Trucks 6
Power Rangers 5
The Fate of the Furious 6
Transformers 4
Thor 2
The Smurfs 1`

Comment: Well, `[^d\n]` would match any run of characters that does not contain the literal **`d`** character, nor newline, so that's not what you mean - which would be `[^0123456789\n]`. Unfortunately this cannot be [ultimately solved with a simple `*scanf`](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/). A regular expression could work, but then that would require a POSIX system. Best option would be to read with `fgets` and reverse scan the number from the end.

Comment: If there's always a space right before digit and the digit is at the end of line, then you could try `strtok()`.

Comment: @Yunnosch it is like the subordinate clause of the first sentence of an answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You have a point. So you would not mind somebody building an answer on that? (By the way, nice link to the basics of `*scanf` ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch I do not reserve any rights for expanding my comments into answers if that's what you mean :d

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know you are relaxed about that. Just trying to nudge a less rep-wealthy user; to make an answer (and maybe to give credit).